# Include QNetwork module

Tags: c++, qt, qtnetwork

First, I've seen this thread : [How to use/include the QtNetwork Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62299816/how-to-use-include-the-qtnetwork-module).
I've followed every step.
these are my includes :

```
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
```

My additionnal include directory path

```
C:\Qt\5.15.1\msvc2019_64\include\QtNetwork
```

My additional library path

```
C:\Qt\5.15.1\msvc2019_64\lib;
```

Right now it compiles with just the includes, but the simple line of code :

```
QTcpSocket* pTcpSocket = new QTcpSocket();
```

creates unresolved externals error.
Now I get that this is due to the linker failure to find the right lib.
But if, such as what was done in the other thread, i try to add this dependency :

```
QtNetwork.lib
```

The compiler will complain that it cannot find this file "QtNetwork.lib".
Indeed, this file isn't in my "C:\Qt\5.15.1\msvc2019_64\lib;" folder.
On QtCreator it was piece of cake to get this to run, simply add "QT += network" to the .pro file, run qmake and work done.
However I am stuck on trying to get this to run on msvc with QT extension tool, any ideas ?

Comment: it would be helpful if you could share .pro file

Comment: @vallabh I don't have a .pro file in msvc

Comment: have you copied QtNetwork.dll file into your debug or release folder?

Comment: @vallabh yes i have, but it's useless unless i can get thinks to compile and link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found the problem, it stems from the fact the lib file is currently named "Qt5Networkd.lib" and not "QtNetworkd.lib" as i had seen on the web. Leaving the answer here in case someone goes across the same trouble.